# Dynamically add rules to input with ANTD in REACT

Tags: reactjs, antd

I need to add rules to the inputs automatically. I want to get the object and add the rules, more or less like the code below, but that doesn't work and I can't do something similar.

Can anyone give me any ideas?

```
const [form] = Form.useForm();

form.getFieldInstance("username").rules=[
          {
            required: true,
            message: 'Please input your username!',
          },
   ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try converting field rules to state array:

```
const [form] = Form.useForm()
const [formItemRules, setFormItemRules] = useState([])

// find the best moment to update rules
setFormItemRules(() => ([{
  required: true, 
  message: 'Please input your username!'
}]))


<Form.Item
  label={'...'}
  name={'...'}
  rules={ formItemRules }
>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```

You can also use an object holding all your form items rules:

```
const [formRules, setFormRules] = useState({
  username: [],
  otherField: []
})

setFormRules((current) => ({
  ...current,
  username: [{
    required: true, 
    message: 'Please input your username!'
  }]
}))

<Form.Item
  label={'...'}
  name={'...'}
  rules={ formRules.username }
>
  <Input />
</Form.Item>
```